# Groupby on a column to get its counts while retaining all other columns intact

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Please take a look at the below input data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ['A','A','B','B','C'], 'Tag':[1,2,3,4,5], 'Field':['X','X','Y','Z','R'] })

  Name  Tag Field
0    A    1     X
1    A    2     X
2    B    3     Y
3    B    4     Z
4    C    5     R
```

I am looking at the counts of "Name" column as an additional column named "Count" while retaining the "Tag" and "Field" column values in tact.

Expected output:

```
  Name  Count  Tag Field
0    A      2    1     X
1    A      2    2     X
2    B      2    3     Y
3    B      2    4     Z
4    C      1    5     R
```

My try:

I could achieve this with a `groupby` and `merge` and its below. However, I am guessing that I am over complicating this and looking for better solutions than mine. Please help.

```
df1 = df.groupby("Name")['Tag'].count().reset_index()
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'Tag' : 'Count'})
df1 = df1.merge(df, on='Name', how='left')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you need `transform`:

```
df["count"] = df.groupby("Name")["Tag"].transform("size")

print (df)

  Name  Tag Field  count
0    A    1     X      2
1    A    2     X      2
2    B    3     Y      2
3    B    4     Z      2
4    C    5     R      1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try

```
df['Count'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: len(df.loc[df['Name'] == x, :]))
```

Comment: Thanks Raghav.. But I am looking at efficient code. "Apply" makes mine slow as its a big file.